# FragmentStateAdapter does not call "createFragment" when its "notifyDataSetChanged" function is called

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

I am using a [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) together with an adapter that minimally extends [FragmentStateAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter), as follows:

```kotlin
class MyAdapter(fragment: Fragment): FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 5
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter has no effect at all. (Calling `notifyItemChanged(position)` works fine.)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8):

I've created a bug report for this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171039652) in IssueTracker. For me, though, even the `notifyItemChanged(position:)` and `notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart:itemCount:)` methods behave incorrectly.

The bug is due to the default implementation of the `FragmentStateAdapter.getItemId(position:)` method which simply returns the `position` passed into it. The `itemId` for each `position` will therefore be the same before and after a `FragmentStateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` call and therefore none of the `Fragment`s will ever be recreated.

One possible workaround is to assign each page a unique id within your `FragmentStateAdapter` implementation and to assign a new id to each page whenever the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method is called. See the `init` block in the `ViewPagerAdapter` class below which facilitates this workaround: An `AdapterDataObserver` object is registered in this `init` block such that it receives a callback whenever `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

    private var counter = 0L
    private var itemIds: List<Long>

    init {
        itemIds = generateListOfItemIds()

        val adapterDataObserver = object : AdapterDataObserver() {

            override fun onChanged() {
                itemIds = generateListOfItemIds()
            }
        }

        registerAdapterDataObserver(adapterDataObserver)
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemIds.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return itemIds[position]
    }

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
        return itemIds.contains(itemId)
    }

    private fun generateListOfItemIds() = (1..5).map { counter++ }
}
```

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/ViewPager2-experiments/tree/master/app2) for a minimal Android application which demonstrates this `ViewPagerAdapter` class.

Answer (score 7):

Before calling [setAdapter(adapter:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)) on your [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) object, call its [setSaveFromParentEnabled(enabled:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setSaveFromParentEnabled(boolean)) method with a value of `false`, i.e. `viewPager.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false)`.

Comment: Man....!! How on earth you got this solution? It worked like charm!!!

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. I called `viewPager.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false)` before calling `viewPager.setAdapter(adapter)` and my adapter's `createFragment(fragment:)` function still was not called when I called my adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the [getItemId(position: Int): Long](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter#getItemId(int)) function on [FragmentStateAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter).

Comment: That's the essence of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64394113/1071320) from 2020. If you have an alternative idea on _how_ to override the `getItemId(position:)` function, please share 

Answer (score 0):

My situation was using `ViewPager2` and `TabLayout` in a `Fragment`. I was trying to pass `LiveData` from the current main `Fragment` to the `Fragment`s in the `ViewPager2`.

DailyTabFragment.kt

```
class DailyTabFragment {
    lateinit var timePeriod: LiveData<TimePeriod>

    companion object {
        fun getInstance(
            selectedTimePeriod: LiveData<TimePeriod>
        ) =
            DailyTabFragment().apply {
                timePeriod = selectedTimePeriod
            }
    }
}
```

There were times my `Fragment` was calling `onCreateView` without any value. Therefore, whenever I used this `LiveData`, I would get an `UninitializedPointerException`. The solution was observing the `LiveData` only if it has been initialized.

```
if (::timePeriod.isInitialized) {
    timePeriod.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        // Do some stuff....
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see how this answer is related to the question. The question is about the `notifyDataSetChanged` function having no impact on the `ViewPager2` object. Your answer is guidance on how to safely initialise a `LiveData` object.