# How can I force or ensure that a Fragment gets recreated by FragmentStateAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I recently found out that a Fragment in my app doesn't seem to be triggering any of its lifecycle methods. `onCreateView`, `onResume`, `onAttach` doesn't get triggered. I thought `Navigation` is just not functioning properly because of my use-case, then I realized the `Fragment` wasn't really directly interacting with `Navigation` but was being displayed using a `ViewPager` by another `Fragment` that actually can interact with `Navigation`. After finding this out, I tried the solutions I found looking around, but unfortunately they didn't work. And most of them is still using deprecated code so it might not really be practical to use them.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
private val fragmentPgLst: MutableList<Fragment> = mutableListOf(Frag1Fragment(), Frag2Fragment())

private fun setupViewPager() {
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(ctx, fragmentPgLst)
    binding!!.vpgMain.adapter = adapter

    binding!!.navMain.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_main_actuators -> binding!!.vpgMain.currentItem = 0
            R.id.nav_main_sensors -> binding!!.vpgMain.currentItem = 1
        }
        true
    }
}

class ViewPagerAdapter (fa: FragmentActivity, private val fragLst: MutableList<Fragment>) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragLst.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragLst[position]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. After digging through the internal code, I found out that `FragmentStateAdapter` is saving the state of its `Fragment`s, and I think that was what's keeping the `Fragment`s from getting recreated. Then I found a way to stop `FragmentStateAdapter` from, I think, saving the state of its `Fragment`.

Here's the answer where I found the fix:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75624931/10464730